# How to implement Transactions with Generic Repository Pattern?

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am developing a .NET Core application where I leverage the Generic Repository pattern and I would like to know how can I implement a transaction:

**IGenericRepository**

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T>
    {
        Task InsertAsync(T insert);
        Task<bool> RemoveAsync(object id);
        Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id,string includeProperties="");
        Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter=null,
                                     int? skip=null,
                                     int? take=null,
                                     Func<IQueryable<T>,IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                                     string includeProperties = "");
        Task SaveAsync();
    }
```

I was looking at [this](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/unit-of-work-csharp-mvc/) implementation which uses UnitOfWork as well, but in .NET Core, I do not have a `DbContextTransaction`.

I am not using UnitOfWork yet. Currently my service looks like this:

```
public class SomeService
{
   IGenericRepository<A> arepo;
   IGenericRepository<B> brepo;
   public SomeService(IGenericRepository<A> arepo,IGenericRepository<B> brepo)
   {
        this.arepo=arepo;
        this.brepo=brepo;
   }
   public async Task DoTransaction(id)
   {
        var a=await arepo.GeyById(id)
        await brepo.RemoveAsync(a.Id);
        await brepo.SaveChangesAsync();
        await arepo.InsertAsync([something]);
        await arepo.SaveChanges();
   }  
}
```

I would want to make this transactional and also, avoid using `SaveChangesAsync` for all repositories that get involved.

What would be a solution?

Comment: EF Core already has implemented repository and UoW patterns. Is there any specific need to wrap it? Some interesting post for you that probably will clarify what i am talking about: https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not expert in entity framework, but I am answering in terms of repository and unit of work.

To begin with, avoid unnecessary wrapper of additional generic repository as you are already using full-ORM. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781877/5779732) answer.

> but in .NET Core i do not have a DbContextTransaction.

The `DbContextTransaction` is important but not a key for implementing unit of work in this case. What is important is `DBContext`. It is `DBContext` that tracks and flushes the changes. You call `SaveChanges` on `DBContext` to notify that you are done.

> I would want to make this transactional

I am sure there must be something available to replace `DbContextTransaction` or to represent transaction.

One way suggested by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#controlling-transactions) is to use it as below:

> ```
> context.Database.BeginTransaction()
> ```

where `context` is `DbContext`.

Other way is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43949175/5779732).

> also ,avoid using SaveChangesAsync for all repos that get involved

That is possible. Do not put `SaveChanges` in repositories. Put it in separate class. Inject that class in each concrete/generic repository. Finally, simply call `SaveChanges` once when you are done. For sample code, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57555384/5779732) question. But, code in that question have a bug which is fixed in the answer I provided to it.